# First time working with Foreign Key leads to Error

Tags: python, django

Hey there I'm new to Django trying to work with a Foreign Key in my **models.py**:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
import datetime

# Create your models here.

CITIES = (
    ('item_1', 'Standort 01'),
    ('item_2', 'Standort 02'),
    ('item_3', 'Standort 03'),
    ('item_4', 'Standort 04'),
)

class Teacher(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    standort = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=CITIES, default='item_1')
    teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start = models.DateField()
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Running `manage.py migrate` led me to this Error:

```
line 947, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '---'
```

After trying to figuring out about some time what my mistake could have been, I'm hoping if someone here can help me out?

Comment: What did you do to get this error?

Comment: Can you show us any records that you have in the database for these models?

Comment: did you already have data for the field that you want to convert to ForeignKey, for example, it might be CharField before

Comment: get this error while doing "python manage.py migrate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by dropping down the database.
I already stored some objects that led me to this error.
After clearing this data, manage.py migrate worked.